# Javascript Replace on button click

Tags: javascript

I'm running a small javascript replace to replace text on a button click and I can't see why it's not working. Could anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/zg4VB/2/

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("#editme").value = replaceLinks($("#editme").val());
})

function replaceLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"[url=$1]$1[/url]"); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.value` is usually the direct *property* of a DOM Input element.  The jQuery function to access or change an element's value is `.val()`

Usefully, `.val()` allows you to pass a function to mutate the current value.  That function is passed the element's index and current value, and the function's return value replaces the original value.    All you need to do is change the signature of your `replaceLinks` function to allow for the `index` parameter (which you can then safely ignore).

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('#editme').val(replaceLinks);  // calls `replaceLinks` to mutate its value
});

function replaceLinks(index, text) {
    ...
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/XzrHP/

Comment: In the way he is using it above it would be a direct property of the jQuery collection

Comment: @ExplosionPills it would, if there were such a property.

Comment: By performing the assignment you create the property.  Of course you wouldn't be able to retrieve it since the reference to the created object is lost immediately, but in theory you could.  Whatever it is, it's *not* a property of the DOM node.

Comment: You're picking nits - all I was trying to say was that he was clearly trying to use the `.value` DOM property on a jQuery collection - a common mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Two issues. First, `$("#editme").value = replaceLinks($("#editme").val());` should be `$("#editme").val(replaceLinks($("#editme").val()));`

Second, your button ID was `id="#button"` and should be `id="button"`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zg4VB/3/)**

Comment: Something so simple! Thank you very much. (Will accept as answer when I can)

Comment: writing `$(el).val(mutator_func($(el).val))` is wasteful and repetitious.  jQuery allows you to just write `$(el).val(mutator_func)`, per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A couple problems: `.value =` should be `.val(`.  It's used both to set and get the value.  You also had the button ID as `#button`, but it should just be `button`.

You could also do `$("#editme").val(replaceLinks);` if you change the arguments of `replaceLinks` to `function replaceLinks(_, text) {`

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/zg4VB/5/

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("#editme").val(replaceLinks);
})

function replaceLinks(_, text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"[url=$1]$1[/url]"); 
}
```

If you want to use `replaceLinks` on strings as well, you could check `arguments` in `replaceLinks` as well: `text = arguments[arguments.length - 1]`

Comment: `_` for unused parameters - Erlang programmer?